# Lug nuts keep snapping off

Tags: tires, troubleshooting, alignment, lug-nut

Why would lug bolts be snapping off constantly and tires wearing faster on the passenger front wheel of a '98 Blazer, 4 wheel drive? The tire is wearing on the outside. It has had a front end alignment and the gentleman who ran the shop told me that the camber was all the way out. What do I have to do to correct this problem?

I had to replace the CV axle on that side and that's when the problem began, I also just replaced the hub as well, both about 5-6 months ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Camber is the angle of the wheel on it's vertical axis - If you have wear on the outside of the tyre, then you have too much positive camber, i.e. the top of the wheel is further out than the bottom - the opposite of the diagram below (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camber_angle)), which shows negative camber.

[image: Negative Camber]

For it to be far enough out to cause such serious problems, I would surmise that something in the suspension is bent. At a guess, I'd say one of the lower arms, as that would lead to the bottom of the wheel being further in than it ought to be, as a bent arm is shorter than a straight one. You might be able to fix it by adjustment or adding shims (a common way of adjusting camber), but that only tends to give a small amount of adjustment - the best option is to replace the damaged part.